# azure Linux vmss extension

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have used the new terraform module for Linux vmss to include monitoring agents as a custom extension, however, the instance doesn't have the "Latest model" when everything is done and manually restart vmss to get a newer model that works but I don't want manual intervention. The previous module doesn't need to manually re-image to get the newest one. did I miss anything?

the code the extension is

```
 "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "oms" {
 name                         = "OmsAgentForLinux"
 depends_on                   = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss]
 virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
 publisher                    = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
 type                         = "OmsAgentForLinux"
 type_handler_version         = "1.11"
  settings = <<-BASE_SETTINGS
 {
  "workspaceId" : "xxxx"
 }
 BASE_SETTINGS

 protected_settings = <<-PROTECTED_SETTINGS
 {
 "workspaceKey" : "xxxxx"
  }
 PROTECTED_SETTINGS
 }
```

Module for creating azure vmss

```
  resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1
  admin_username      = "administer"

 admin_ssh_key {
 username   = "administer"
 public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

 source_image_reference {
 publisher = "Canonical"
 offer     = "UbuntuServer"
 version   = "latest"
  }

 os_disk {
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
 caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
  name    = "example"
  primary = true

    ip_configuration {
    name      = "internal"
    primary   = true
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
     }
     }
    }
```

the old module does not specify OS

```
 "azurerm_virtual_machine" "demovm"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected behavior as by default the upgrade policy is set to **manual**. In this mode, when you update the scale set model, nothing happens to existing VMs.

From [how to add an extension to all VMs in my virtual machine scale set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq#how-do-i-add-an-extension-to-all-vms-in-my-virtual-machine-scale-set),

> If update policy is set to **automatic**, redeploying the template
>   with the new extension properties updates all VMs.
>
> If update policy is set to **manual**, first update the extension, and
>   then manually update all instances in your VMs.

In this case, if you don't want manual intervention, you may try to use **automatic** upgrade policy.

References:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_scale_set.html
- https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/azure-scale-set-upgrade-policy-explained/

Comment: thanks for your time, just the FYI the module "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" doesn't specify upgraed_policy. I have used for years working just fine but the new one azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set it does plus ask for lb health probe resource id.  so better use the old one for now.